# How to create JSON from an Array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json

I want to create a JSON list using an array and foreach loop in PHP.
I am trying this code :

```
    <?php
$test=array("Camera","Performance","Storage");
foreach ($test as $key=>$value){
$myArr = array($value=>array(
    "Rating" => "3",
    "Content" => "This is an Awesome content" ,
    "key" => $key
));
echo json_encode($myArr);
}

?>
```

I am getting this output from this code:

```
 {"Camera":{"Rating":"3","Content":"This is an Awesome content","key":0}}

 {"Performance":{"Rating":"3","Content":"This is an Awesome content","key":1}}

 {"Storage":{"Rating":"3","Content":"This is an Awesome content","key":2}}
```

Instead, I want output like this:

```
 {
"Camera":{"Rating":"3","Content":"This is an Awesome content","key":0},

"Performance":{"Rating":"3","Content":"This is an Awesome content","key":1},

"Storage":{"Rating":"3","Content":"This is an Awesome content","key":2}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're overwriting `$myArr` every time through the loop. Instead, append a new key/value pair every time:

```
$test=array("Camera","Performance","Storage");
foreach ($test as $key => $value){
  $myArr[$value] = array(
      "Rating" => "3",
      "Content" => "This is an Awesome content",
      "key" => $key
  );
}

echo json_encode($myArr);
```